# Unable to set cookie in React by using Django

Tags: reactjs, django, cookies, django-rest-framework, setcookie

I created a React website that uses API to communicate with the Django backend. I use ***djangorestframework*** to create API. I need to set cookie to react but there is no update cookie on React site.

views.py

```
class Test(generics.CreateAPIView):
    def post(self,request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = Response()
        response.set_cookie('test_cookie', 'MY COOKIE VALUE')
        return response
```

How to fix this problem? What topic should I know to fix that problem?

Comment: UPDATE: cookie is able to set on postman but unable on React/Chrome

Comment: this is the hint from Ghatgpt. 1.CORS: If the React application is running on a different domain than the Django application, you may need to set up Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) to allow the browser to send the cookie with requests to the Django application. You can use the django-cors-headers package to set up CORS in your Django application.

Comment: 2. SameSite attribute: The SameSite attribute is used to prevent cross-site request forgery attacks by restricting the use of cookies to first-party contexts. If the SameSite attribute is set to Strict or Lax, the cookie may not be sent with a cross-site request from the React application. You can set the SameSite attribute to None to allow the cookie to be sent with cross-site requests, but this should only be done if the cookie contains no sensitive information.

Comment: 3.Cookie path: The cookie path determines the URLs to which the cookie is sent. If the cookie path is set to a more specific path than the URL of the React application, the cookie may not be sent with requests to the React application. Make sure that the cookie path is set to a broader path or to the root path (/).